# Set __init__ attributes based on __init__ arguments

Tags: python, class, dynamic, attributes

I would like to reduce the number of rows in class definition and create __init __ attributes that have same name as __init __ arguments. Is this possible?

```
class Num():
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg3 = 'three'
        # some magic here

a = Num('one', 'two')  # instance
```

then

```
print(a.arg1)  # one
print(a.arg2)  # two
print(a.arg3)  # three
```

Comment: The current superclass of `Num` is `object`, whose `__init__` method doesn't take any (non-`self`) parameters. Hence the error you didn't include in your post. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the rest of the question.

Comment: Methods or attributes? Are you aware of [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)? When you say "inherit" do you mean inherit from another class?

Comment: I modified the title to 'Set class methods' instead of confusing 'Inherit'.

Comment: @learning_python_self per your last edit, `dataclasses` are exactly what you are looking for. They generate an `__init__` for you so you only need to specify the types of the arguments. You can also just add `arg3: str = 'three'` in the body to set your third arg.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately dataclasses are a library. Nothing out of box, other than locals?

Comment: There's little benefit to reducing the size of `__init__` for its own sake. If you feel too many lines are taken up assigning arguments to attributes, that's possibly a sign that your class needs to be redesigned rather than needing to reduce boilerplate.

Comment: They are included in the standard lib. All you need is `from dataclasses import dataclass` at the top of your file. Almost every Python installation above 3.7 will have it.

Comment: @learning_python_self The standard library has the same status as any other feature in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to infer it from the parameter list, you could do tricky stuff with `locals()`:

```
class Num:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        for var, val in locals().items():
            if var != 'self':
                self.__setattr__(var, val)
        self.arg3 = "three"


a = Num('one', 'two')  # instance
print(a.arg1)  # one
print(a.arg2)  # two
print(a.arg3)  # three
```

A better solution would be to use a dataclass:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Num:
    arg1: str
    arg2: str
    arg3: str = "three"


a = Num('one', 'two')  # instance
print(a.arg1)  # one
print(a.arg2)  # two
print(a.arg3)  # three
```

Comment: "mildly repetitive but much less confusing" -- don't most people often repeat argument names as class methods though, hence the use case?

Comment: Or just have a dataclass with a default for `arg3`, or [post-init processing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing).

Comment: Wondering if something simpler than locals().items(), which otherwise works fine.... Dataclasses are a library, which I prefer to avoid but good to know nonetheless.

Comment: aha yes, dataclass with a default works as long as you don't need anything else in the __init__!

Comment: There is no reason to avoid modules in the standard library. Many of them incur no runtime overhead to import, because they are already baked into the interpreter. (`dataclasses` isn't one of those, but the overhead of importing it is negligible compared the time it takes the rest of a non-trivial script to execute.)